# What would be the most efficient event that I should hookup to when trying to display the row number of a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using `dataGridView` in `virtualMode` and I have tried to use *CellPainting event* to display the row number but the fact of updating the `headerCell.Value` is causing the *CellPainting* event to continue to fire in an `infinite loop`. I looked at RowPostPaint, but that appears to also fire in an infinite loop.  Is there a more efficient event or perhaps a way to disable *CellPainting* Event from triggering when I am in this code.

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please tell us if your in VS what version, if your in Winforms or Asp.net or WPF or anything else please, that would help.

Comment: VS2010 and Winform application

Answer (score 0):

Just add a field to your class and check if you've been in that part of the code before like this

```
 void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.theRowCountWasPainted) return;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
            this.theRowCountWasPainted = true;
        }
    }
```

Whenever you need to repaint it again just set the this.theRowCountWasPainted to false